# Creating Latex tables for Zelig Amelia output

Tags: r, r-zelig

I'm running into a problem creating a display table for a simple linear model using Zelig and Amelia II imputed data.

```
 > summary(z.out)
Model: Combined Imputations 

                         Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)              7.57e+01  1.21e+01    6.26  3.9e-10
GDP                     -1.71e-05  7.12e-06   -2.40  0.01641
biz_fund_public_percent -3.23e+00  1.42e+00   -2.28  0.02280
GERD                     6.50e-04  8.83e-04    0.74  0.46205
BERD                     1.16e-04  9.85e-04    0.12  0.90598
Gov_BERD                -2.52e+00  3.86e-01   -6.54  6.3e-11
thematic_percent        -1.36e+01  1.96e+01   -0.70  0.48650
stem_percent             2.16e+01  1.57e+01    1.37  0.17116
pmc                     -1.51e+01  4.28e+00   -3.53  0.00042

For results from individual imputed datasets, use summary(x, subset = i:j)
Statistical Warning: The GIM test suggests this model is misspecified
 (based on comparisons between classical and robust SE's).
 We suggest you run diagnostics to ascertain the cause, respecify the model
 and run it again.

Next step: Use 'setx' method

> screenreg(z.out)
Returning fitted model objects for each imputed data set in a list.
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"list"’
>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.